# What is Judy's and Nick's relationship?

Tags: character, ending, zootopia

At the end of ***Zootopia*** we observe that Judy and Nick have become really close to each other but are they maintaining a best friend type relationship or a romantic relationship? I think that it is only a friend relation, but is there any evidence of this?

Comment: You can always say ''I just love you'' but you can mean it like ''youre my best friend'' or ''youre the best''

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During the movie they become good friends. As to that ending scene and the future after that, it seems it's intentionally ambiguous. The directors (Mainly Rich Moore) seem to be having great fun playing with this fact on Twitter.

[See here, the confirmation they are friends:](https://twitter.com/_rich_moore/status/702848375121711104)

> Diego Noriega @Diego_Noriega10:
>   @_rich_moore Already seen the movie and I have to say it was awesome; but I have a question which is the relationship between Judy and Nick?
>
> **Rich Moore @_rich_moore Retweeted Diego Noriega
>
>   Hi Diego! Judy and Nick are BBFF's: bunny best friends forever ❤️**

[And here, in which one of the directors teases about the future](https://twitter.com/_rich_moore/status/703028988801916929):

> zootopiaisthebest @zootopiathebest:
>   @_rich_moore I luv your film! But sometimes, friends could be couple, isn't it? Because..As nick&judy said at Ending, they love each other..
>
> **Rich Moore ‏@_rich_moore Retweeted zootopiaisthebest
>
>   Mmmaybe...I guess we'll just have to wait and see what happens in the future**

Comment: Actually, is there even such a thing as inter-species romance in Zootopia? I don't remember seeing any such couples. Maybe they're saving miscegenation to be their social issue in the sequel.

Comment: There not being such a thing would be extremely unrealistic for the society they built.  The directors confirmed as much and that yes it is a thing and it's not a huge deal.  In fact in the credits you can see Judy's neighbors share a hyphenated last name, possibly implying they are both a same-sex and inter-species married couple.

Answer (score 1):

There they are at the end of the movie couple, proves this conversation:

> **Nick:** You know you love me.
>   **Judy:** Do I know that? Yes I do.

Comment: Unfortunately, even if people admit they love each other, that doesn't mean they are a romantic couple

Comment: There are at least two moments in which it seems that Judy has _stronger than friendship feelings_ for Nick: 1- In the gondola lift she says that he is **much more than what others think of him**. 2- Later, she asks him, papers in hand, to enroll with her in the police to be **partners**.